# Fitting a rectangle within another rectangle

Tags: geometry, packing-problem

What are the restrictions such that we can fix a rectangle of dimension $a\times b$ into another rectangle of size $c \times d$? What about if we try to fit it inside a square of side $c$?

Comment: Can the rectangle be rotated?

Comment: yes it can be rotated

Comment: You should state what you already know.  For example, it should be obvious that the area of the smaller rectangle should not be bigger ($ab\le cd$) and that the diagonal of the smaller rectangle should not be longer ($\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\le\sqrt{c^2+d^2}$).

Comment: Given one side $a$ and an angle $\theta$ between that side and a side of the larger rectangle, elementary geometry should yield a formula for the largest possible $b$. Then you can maximize that formula over $\theta$, for example.